# Time Machine asks for a backup disk by the wrong name

Tags: time-machine

I have a time machine backup drive that I have renamed to *Home Backup*. Whenever I forget to take backups, OS X tells me "you haven't backed up to the drive *My Passport* for 10 days"

Running `tmutil destinationinfo` I get this:

```
Name          : My Passport
Kind          : Local
Mount Point   : /Volumes/Home Backup
ID            : XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
```

I looked in the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` file, but it doesn't contain the destination name.

How can I get the volume name and the time machine internal name to match again?

To be clear, this is more of an annoyance than a problem, the backups work flawlessly when I remember to give OS X the Home Backup disk when it asks for My Passport. :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click the My Passport drive and go to Get Info and change the name in the "Name and Extension" section

Comment: The problem is there is no My Passport drive. I have only a backup drive called Home Backup.